# The Intern: Polling Until Element is Visible

Tags: intern

Is there a way in Intern that I can poll until an element is visible? A lot of elements in my website are in the dom but are hidden, so every time I do a "find for" element X after it is supposed to appear, it fails because the element clearly breaks one of the visible attributes that selenium checks.

I've tried the helper function "pollUntil" but I can't seem to get that to work. Dojo seems to not like document.getElement*()

Helper Function that is passed into pollUntil

```
//this is a helper function for pollUntil
//first we want to find an element by class name and text
var elementVisibleAndText = function(elems, innerText){
        elems = document.getElementsByClassName(elems);
        //if we can't even find it, we return null
        //but if we do find it, we want to return a
        //not null element
        if (!elems || elems.length == 0){
            return null; 
        }

        //now let's look at all of the elements found by
        //in elems, and see if the innerHTML matches. If it 
        //does then we want to return that it was found
        var each;
        for(each in elems){
            if(elems[each].innerHTML == innerText)
                return (elems[each].offsetWidth > 0 && elems[each].offsetHeight > 0) ? elems[each] : null;
        }
        //else return null if nothing is found in the elements

        return null;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/pollUntil.html. Intern uses leadfoot - so you should have access to this functionality.

```
var Command = require('leadfoot/Command');
var pollUntil = require('leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil');

new Command(session)
    .get('http://example.com')
    .then(pollUntil('return document.getElementById("a");', 1000))
    .then(function (elementA) {
        // element was found
    }, function (error) {
        // element was not found
    });
```

To use the function within one of your tests - you would import it using the following path:

```
'intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil'
```

Answer (score 1):

I run into this issue all the time and we used the pollUntil functionality of intern to write a few helper utilities. In our tests we use something like `.then(pollUntil(util.element_visible_by_class(), ['toast_notification'], 22000))`

In a separate `util.js` file we have

```
/**
 * Our shared utility for unit testing
 */
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'require',
    'intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil'

], function (registerSuite, assert, require, util, pollUntil) {
    return {
        element_visible_by_class: function(elem) {
            return function(elem) {
                elem = document.getElementsByClassName(elem);
                if (!elem || elem.length == 0) { return null; }
                elem = elem[0];
                return (elem.offsetWidth > 0 && elem.offsetHeight > 0) ? elem : null;
            }  
        },

        element_visible_by_id: function(elem) {
            return function(elem) {
                elem = document.getElementById(elem);
                if (!elem) { return null; }
                return (elem.offsetWidth > 0 && elem.offsetHeight > 0) ? elem : null;
            }  
        },
        element_hidden_by_id: function(elem) {
            return function(elem) {
                elem = document.getElementById(elem);
                if (!elem) { return null; }
                return (elem.offsetWidth > 0 && elem.offsetHeight > 0) ? null : elem;
            }  
        },
        element_hidden_by_class: function(elem) {
            return function(elem) {
                elem = document.getElementsByClassName(elem);
                if (!elem || elem.length == 0) { return null; }
                elem = elem[0];
                return (elem.offsetWidth > 0 && elem.offsetHeight > 0) ? null : elem;
            }  
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: That's exactly what I do on my current project and works fine for the purpose of the OP. +1